# Import all schtasks .xml files inside the current directory via batch

Tags: xml, batch-file, scheduled-tasks

I know it's possible to import multiple tasks like this:

```
schtasks.exe /create /TN "Task 1 Name" /XML "Full_Path_of_Backup_XML_File"
schtasks.exe /create /TN "Task 2 Name" /XML "Full_Path_of_Backup_XML_File"
schtasks.exe /create /TN "Task 3 Name" /XML "Full_Path_of_Backup_XML_File"
```

But I'd prefer a more dynamic way to import all schtasks .xml files inside the current directory. Much like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10952703/executing-all-the-reg-files-from-batch-file) batch here (.xml instead of .reg):

```
rem @echo off
cls
SET folder=%~dp0
for %%i in ("%folder%*.reg") do (regedit /s "%%i")
echo done
pause
EXIT
```

Can someone guide me to the right direction? :)

Comment: What have you tried on your own so far, where are you stuck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean that you want to iterate through every XML file that is located in the same directory as the batch-file script? And then create a scheduled task with every XML file that was found? If that is the case you could try something like this (assuming the XML files are valid to create scheduled tasks with):

```
@echo off

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for %%e in ("%~dp0*.xml") do (
  set /a "count+=1"
  schtasks /create /tn "Task !count! Name" /xml "%%~e"
)
```

---

If you need to be able to pass XML file names that contain exclamation marks to the `schtasks` command-line tool, use the following code instead:

```
@echo off

setlocal disabledelayedexpansion
set "count=1"

for %%e in ("%~dp0*.xml") do (
  set "file=%%~e"
  setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
  schtasks /create /tn "Task !count! Name" /xml "!file!"
  endlocal & set /a "count+=1"
)
```

---

> Still one question, how to name the tasks like their .xml filenames?

This will actually simplify things because there is no need to expand a separate variable within the for-loop body during execution time:

```
@echo off

setlocal disabledelayedexpansion

for %%e in ("%~dp0*.xml") do (
  schtasks /create /tn "%%~ne" /xml "%%~e"
)
```

Comment: Thanks! It works! I directly tried the second script to avoid future compatibility issues. Still one question, how to name the tasks like their .xml filenames?

Comment: @Yethat You're welcome. I've updated my answer and provided another approach that uses the file name (without extension) of the XML files as the newly created task names.

Comment: Very nice! :) One last thing: If tasks already exist - how to overwrite the old ones?

Comment: @Yethat The `/f` switch of the `schtasks` command-line tool states the following: "Forcefully creates the task and suppresses warnings if the specified task already exists."

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I am new to batch scripting, what does "%~dp0*.xml"  this expression mean? Are we specifying a directory here?