# Grab all subfolders names at all levels as well as their files' names and then use them; ignore batch file's name

Tags: batch-file

I have the following script (based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45084641/2418445)) that allows to import all Task Scheduler tasks from the current folder using the files' names as tasks' names:

```
@echo off

setlocal disabledelayedexpansion

for %%e in ("%~dp0*") do (
  schtasks /create /tn "%%~ne" /xml "%%~e"
)
```

I need to modify it in a way so that it also looks for files in all subfolders (at all levels) and creates tasks accordingly. E. g. if the batch is in some folder along with the task files named "Dummy1", "Dummy2", "Dummy3", the tasks shall be imported as "Dummy1", "Dummy2", "Dummy3". If the folder with the batch file also contains the subfolder "Subby1" with the tasks named "Dummy1", "Dummy2", those tasks shall be imported as "Subby1\Dummy1", "Subby1\Dummy2". If the folder with the batch file contains the subfolder "Subby1\Sub-Subby" with the tasks named "Dummy1", "Dummy2", those tasks shall be imported as "Subby1\Sub-Subby\Dummy1", "Subby1\Sub-Subby\Dummy2", etc.

And also I want to make it ignore the batch file itself, but without excluding .bat extension as such.

I tried this, but I suck at batch scripting, so obviously it didn't work, and I don't even understand why:

```
for %%e in ("%~I") do (
  schtasks /create /tn "%%~I\%%~ne" /xml "%%~e"
)
```

As for excluding the batch file, I have no idea how to do it whatsoever.

Comment: I need a script that handles both the files that reside in the same folder as the batch file (excluding the batch file itself) and also all files in all subfolders at all levels (and imports them with the same folder structure). I don't know what you mean by executable.

Comment: As a basis: `for /R "%~dp0." %%e in (*.*) do ( ... )`?

Comment: @aschipfl and how do I refer to subfolder names after that? So it imports files with the respective folder structure.

Comment: `for /R "%~dp0." in (*.*) do (
  schtasks /create /tn "%%~fe\%%~ne" /xml "%%~e"
)` the script closes upon start.

Comment: Instead of double-clicking, run the batch file by opening a command prompt window and typing the script path/name, then you can read amy returned error. Note that `%%~fe` returns the full absolute path...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change your [standard `for` loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for2.html) to a [`for /R` loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for_r.html) to include sub-directories too:

```cmd
rem // Iterate over all files in the directory tree rooted at the parent directory of this script:
set "RELPATH=#"
for /R "%~dp0." %%e in (*.*) do (
    if not defined RELPATH (
        rem // This creates scheduled tasks named of the pure base file names:
        schtasks /Create /TN "%%~ne" /XML "%%~e"
    ) else (
        rem // This creates scheduled tasks named of the relative file paths:
        set "ITEM=%%~e"
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        schtasks /Create /TN "!ITEM:*%~dp0=!" /XML "%%~e"
        endlocal
    )
)
```

Since this uses [sub-string substitution](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html), the above code might fail under certain circumstances, for example when the parent directory of the script contains an equal-to sign. However, there is a solution that can also handle such cases, using [`xcopy /L`](https://ss64.com/nt/xcopy.html), which returns relative paths without actually copying anything (due to `/L`) and thus avoiding string manipulation. The [`for /F` loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) captures the output of `xcopy`, removes the preceding drive letter (like `D:`) and filters out the final summary line (like `# File(s)`):

```cmd
pushd "%~dp0." && (
    for /F "tokens=2 delims=:" %%e in ('xcopy /L /S /I "*.*" "%TEMP%"') do (
        schtasks /Create /TN "%%~e" /XML "%%~e"
    )
    popd
)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked perfectly. I found batch script language hard to follow, tbh, and I really appreciate your explanations.